# T-SQL List of Results plus one row with a summary of less important values

Tags: t-sql

Table is populated as follows

```
CustomerName                  SalesValue
CusA                          100
CusB                          250
CusC                          900
CusD                          1200
CusE                          2500
```

I want a query which will list sales values for all of my customers if the value (per customer) is over 1000. If it's less, then I just want to see one summary row indicating total value of all customers <= 1000. Results would look something like this:

```
CusE                          2500
CusD                          1200

(Small Value Customers)       1250

Total                         4950
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
WITH sales AS
(
    SELECT [CustomerName], [SalesValue],
       CustSales = SUM(SalesValue)OVER(PARTITION BY CustomerName)
    FROM dbo.Sales
)
SELECT CustomerName, CustSales FROM(
  SELECT 1 AS Source, 
       CustomerName, 
       CustSales = SUM(CustSales) FROM sales 
  GROUP BY  CustomerName
  HAVING SUM(CustSales) > 1000

  UNION ALL

  SELECT 2 As Source, 
       CustomerName = '(Small Value Customers)', 
       CustSales = SUM(CustSales) FROM sales 
  WHERE CustSales <= 1000

  UNION ALL

  SELECT 3 As Source, 
       CustomerName = 'Total', 
       CustSales = SUM(CustSales) FROM sales 
) AS X
ORDER BY X.Source, X.CustSales DESC
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0d85a/26/0)

Comment: The CTE and the select seem unnecessary to me.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
  DECLARE @LargeCustomersSum INT

  SELECT @LargeCustomersSum = SUM(SalesValue)
  FROM YourTable
  WHERE SalesValue >= 1000

  DECLARE @SmallCustomersSum INT

  SELECT @SmallCustomersSum = SUM(SalesValue)
  FROM YourTable
  WHERE SalesValue <= 1000

  SELECT 'Large Value Customers', @LargeCustomersSum
  UNION   
  SELECT CustomerName, SalesValue
  FROM YourTable
  ORDER BY SalesValue DESC
  WHERE SalesValue >= 1000

  UNION
  SELECT 'Small Value Customers', @SmallCustomersSum
  UNION   
  SELECT CustomerName, SalesValue
  FROM YourTable
  ORDER BY SalesValue DESC
  WHERE SalesValue <= 1000

  UNION
  SELECT 'Total', @LargeCustomersSum + @SmallCustomersSum
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the query

```
 select SalesValue, CustomerName from cus_sales where SalesValue > 1000
 UNION 
  select sum(SalesValue) as Sum, 'Others' as CustomerName from cus_sales where SalesValue <= 1000 
 UNION 
 select sum(SalesValue) as Sum, 'Total' as CustomerName from cus_sales
```

and [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/15402/8)

Comment: this would produce the SUM and only return one row, the OP has indicated that they would like all customers to be displayed with the totals

Answer (score 0):

Option for SQLServer2008+ with [GROUP BY ROLLUP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510427%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

```
SELECT ISNULL(CASE WHEN SalesValue > 1000 THEN CustomerName 
                   ELSE 'SmallValueCustomers' END, 'Total') AS CustomerName, 
       SUM(SalesValue) AS SumSalesValue
FROM dbo.sales
GROUP BY ROLLUP(CASE WHEN SalesValue > 1000 THEN CustomerName 
                     ELSE 'SmallValueCustomers' END)
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/78ae4a/1)

OR If you cannot use GROUP BY clause with ROLLUP operation

```
SELECT CASE WHEN SalesValue > 1000 THEN CustomerName 
            ELSE 'SmallValueCustomers' END AS CustomerName, 
       SUM(SalesValue) AS SumSalesValue
FROM dbo.sales
GROUP BY CASE WHEN SalesValue > 1000 THEN CustomerName 
              ELSE 'SmallValueCustomers' END
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Total', SUM(SalesValue)
FROM dbo.sales
```